# nodejs selenium-webdriver checking current url of newly opened tabs

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing a Firefox web extension using mocha and Node.js selenium-webdriver.

The extension adds a button to the page at `https://example.com/`, which, when clicked, opens 2 new tabs, `https://example.com/a/` and `https://example.com/b/`.

I want to then have the extension modify the content of those pages, but first I want to start by checking their URL.

Below is the relevant part of my test and three (among the many) unsuccessful tries:

```
// test.js
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

const By = webdriver.By;
const until = webdriver.until;
const Button = webdriver.Button;
const Key = webdriver.Key;

describe('my extension', function(){

  let driver;

  this.timeout(15000);

  before(async function(){
    // setting up driver with extension
  });

  after(function(){
    driver.quit();
  });

  describe('open tab button', function(){
    it('opens 2 tabs when button is clicked', async function(){
      // getting https://example.com/
      // clicking button
      await driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(windowHandles) {
        expect(windowHandles.length).to.equal(3); // PASS

        let tab1 = windowHandles[0];
        let tab2 = windowHandles[1];
        let tab3 = windowHandles[2];

        // CODE FOR UNSUCCESSFULL ATTEMPTS (SEE BELOW)
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Attempt #1

```
driver.switchTo().window(tab1).then(() => {
  driver.getCurrentUrl().then(url => {console.log('current url: "' + url + '"');});
}); 

driver.switchTo().window(tab2).then(() => {
  driver.getCurrentUrl().then(url => {console.log('current url: "' + url + '"');});
}); 

driver.switchTo().window(tab3).then(() => {
  driver.getCurrentUrl().then(url => {console.log('current url: "' + url + '"');});
});
```

I get

```
current url: "https://example.com/"
current url: "https://example.com/"
current url: "https://example.com/"
```

Attempt #2

```
driver.switchTo().window(tab1).then(() => {console.log('switched to tab1')});
driver.sleep(250);
driver.getCurrentUrl().then(url => {console.log('current url: "' + url + '"');});

driver.switchTo().window(tab2).then(() => {console.log('switched to tab2')});
driver.sleep(250);
driver.getCurrentUrl().then(url => {console.log('current url: "' + url + '"');});

driver.switchTo().window(tab3).then(() => {console.log('switched to tab3')});
driver.sleep(250);
driver.getCurrentUrl().then(url => {console.log('current url: "' + url + '"');});
```

I get

```
current url: "https://example.com/"
```

1 passing (7s)

```
current url: "https://example.com/"
current url: "https://example.com/"

switched to tab1
switched to tab2
switched to tab3
```

Attempt #3

```
driver.switchTo().window(tab1).then(() => {
  console.log('switched to tab1');
  driver.getCurrentUrl().then(url => {console.log('current url: "' + url + '"');});
});

driver.switchTo().window(tab2).then(() => {
  console.log('switched to tab2');
  driver.getCurrentUrl().then(url => {console.log('current url: "' + url + '"');});
});

driver.switchTo().window(tab3).then(() => {
  console.log('switched to tab3');
  driver.getCurrentUrl().then(url => {console.log('current url: "' + url + '"');});
});
```

I get

```
switched to tab1
switched to tab2
switched to tab3
(node:26698) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:46707
(node:26698) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:26698) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:46707
(node:26698) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:46707
```

I am stuck after trying many other things, googling as much as I could. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only "solution" I found so far was to downgrade `selenium-webdriver` to the previous stable version, `3.6.0` at the time of writting:

```
npm install --save-dev selenium-webdriver@3.6.0
```

Then the following code worked:

```
driver.switchTo().window(tab1).then(() => {
  driver.getCurrentUrl().then(url => {console.log('current url: "' + url + '"');});
}); 

driver.switchTo().window(tab2).then(() => {
  driver.getCurrentUrl().then(url => {console.log('current url: "' + url + '"');});
}); 

driver.switchTo().window(tab3).then(() => {
  driver.getCurrentUrl().then(url => {console.log('current url: "' + url + '"');});
});
```